# What if I don't know my previous visa number for the Indian e-Tourist visa application?

Tags: visas, india, applications

I have been to India before, but have since renewed my passport so have no record of previous visa details. What does one do about completing this question online?
I am French and we are not allowed to keep old passports.

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  If you have no access to your previous passport the most obvious answer is that you have or had a visa but info is unavailable because passport is lost, stolen, or otherwise unavailable provide such details.

Answer (score 8):

Contrary to what honorable @uncovery suggested, I wouldn't recommend stating that you haven't been there. Ethics aside, India scrutinizes visa applications carefully (they seem to be afraid of people of Pakistani origin), so your incorrect information is likely to be uncovered.

Note that Indian visa application form asks for a lot of information which is not going to change (for example, your parents names and places of birth), so it is quite easy for them to match you in a computer.

What I suggest to do is to:

1. State correctly that you have been issued a visa before, and been to India.
2. State "Yes. See attachment 1" in "Have you ever visited India?" question.
3. Add a document titled "Attachment 1" where you explain that your previous passport with Indian visa and travel details is not returned to you, and thus you do not have those details. State the year where you been issued a visa, and a year when you visit, if you remember. This should be enough.

Comment: The OP asked about a visa form that could be filled out online. For the electronic tourist visa (which was introduced in November 2014), it worked for me to write “Unknown” in the visa number field.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem recently. I simply typed NA and it passed without a problem

Comment: And how about date of issue? 10 years ago I have no memory of that :/

Comment: I just estimated the date as best as I could. I forget if the form requires the exact day. If not I imagine I only gave the year and the month

Comment: It requires an exact date that is later than the date of birth of the applicant. It's shitty. I've chosen year and month and a random date from this month. Lets hope it works.