# Does any country punch or used to punch a hole through the whole passport in some cases, and if so, in which cases (e.g., passport cancelation)?

Tags: passports

I [read](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/187950/1810):

> I believe I’ve seen a hole punched through the whole booklet and a corner cut on all pages (except the cover IIRC) but that was a very very long while ago. The hole may have been a different case than just a cancelled passport though, can’t remember.

Does any country punch or used to punch a hole through the whole passport in some cases, and if so, in which cases (e.g., passport cancelation)?

Comment: It might be better to first **accept** (or at least **react to** in some form) an answer to your previous questions on such topics. Otherwise peaple may ask why you are asking the questions when you seem not to be interested in any of the given answers. [2023-01-15: How did adding new pages to a US passport use to work? - Travel Stack Exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/178825/how-did-adding-new-pages-to-a-us-passport-use-to-work/178855#178855)

Comment: @MarkJohnson All answers were equally good, "thank you" comments sometimes get removed, SE doesn't have a "thank you" button unlike Quora beyond the upvote/accept, and I don't care how people assess my interests. Thanks for your answer though, appreciated!

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, if all answers are equally good please select one for whatever reason, (most helpful person in other questions, least rep, nicer way of writing,...) as it helps the site.

Comment: @Willeke sounds good I've accepted the most upvoted answer.

Comment: The same effect is achieved for GB expired passports by chopping the corner off the front cover and the next page (which has the photograph and details). I have never experienced a hole though.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I have several old Dutch passports here with 2 holes (diameter around 1cm) punched through. Not sure if they will still do this. Next expiry is in a few years, maybe I'll find out then. So these are expired passports - people want to save them because of entry stamps etcetera.

Comment: Yes the holes do go through stamps if they happen to be in the spots where the holes are, so if you have stamps which are important you may need to ask for an other way to invalidate the old passport.

Answer (score 4):

I do believe that it is quite common that expired passports are punched if the owner wants to keep the passport, so I would not be surprised if this question will end up with a lot of 'me too' answers. Most of my expired Norwegian passports have been punched with a regular hole punch. The last time I renewed my passport, a corner of the plastic page with the identification data was cut off instead.

[image: Three different styles of hole punch]
Image source: [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:3_perforators.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some of my collection. US appears to punch but only the first 2 pages. Germany cuts off a corner. I'm not sure that there is single way to do this and perhaps some of the details are left to the officer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Korea used to stamp VOID on them. No other mark.

[image: 1990s Korean passport]
[image: 1990s Korean passport cover]

They punch VOID through the  cover and ID page now.

[image: Recent Korean passport]

France used to stamp ANNULE on all pages.
[image: French early 1990s passport]

Now they cut a corner on the cover and ID page, and stamp ANNULE a couple of times.

[image: More recent French passport]

I don't remember seeing a passport punched all the way through.

Comment: Please avoid adding answers that do not add to the information already available if they do not answer the question. It has been established that at least one country does or did make holes through the whole of the passport and that others do not do that.