# How best to provide lost details of old travel to India for Indian Urgent Business Visa from UK

Tags: visas, india

I am a UK consultant and have to travel to Delhi for business meetings with my Indian customer company. I am trying to apply for an urgent business visa.

The online form asks:

- Have you ever visited India before? Yes / No
- Enter the address of stay during your last visit
- Cities previously visited in India
- Last Indian Visa No/Currently valid Indian Visa No.
- Type of Visa
- Place of Issue
- Place of Issue
- Date of Issue

and I have visited India, once, in 1980. I can remember one address (the Oberoi, Bombay as was, although I think the hotel has since moved) and make a stab at the cities visited, but have no idea about a visa. I no longer have that passport. So my question is: **did UK nationals need a visa to visit India in 1980?**

Any suggestions as to how to fill in this online form, please?

I've since found [What if I don't know my previous visa number for the Indian e-Tourist visa application?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22069/what-if-i-dont-know-my-previous-visa-number-for-the-indian-e-tourist-visa-appli) which suggests just writing "unknown" in there. Is that a good idea?

Comment: what an interesting question !   >> PURELY << one man's opinion, since it was 40 years ago I wouldn't even mention it (based on much recent experience getting Indian business visas).  Again that is >> JUST << an honest opinion from someone on the net.

Comment: still a lovely hotel, BTW  :)  :)

Comment: The answer you linked to is from a user with good reputation score on this site, which is some indication that it's a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

Taking the advice from [What if I don't know my previous visa number for the Indian e-Tourist visa application?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22069/what-if-i-dont-know-my-previous-visa-number-for-the-indian-e-tourist-visa-appli), I entered "unknown" where the form asked for the visa number, and "visit visa" for the type of visa.

I took the completed forms and other required documentation to the India Visa centre in Hounslow, London, where I was efficiently served by a helpful woman who checked everything and took my passport. She made no comment at all about the entry on the form. My passport, complete with visa, was returned by courier after 3 working days.